# ReactJS: Using one button in child component disables a second button?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a simple Recipe box in which people can add recipes and it will save to their `localStorage`. Currently I have a popup in which to add recipes to the box, which is then saved. You can see the interface below:

[image: Current Codepen]

When I simply press the "close me" button, I can toggle between the main screen and the popup as many times as I want. However, if I first click "Add recipe", the "close me" button no longer works and fires an error: (this.setState in parent Component) is not defined.

Any info on why this is happening and how to fix it is greatly appreciated.

Here's a link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/JpPbZd?editors=0110

Here's my code. The two classes that are interacting with this behavior are the Box class and the Addpopup class:

```
class Mainbutton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.toggleClose}>
        Add recipe
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Recipes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isExpanded: false,
      height: 0
    }
  }

  handleToggle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      isExpanded: !this.state.isExpanded,
      height: this.refs.inner.clientHeight
    });
  }

  render() {

    const currentHeight = this.state.isExpanded ? this.state.height : 0;

    const ingredients = this.props.item.ingredients.map(ingredient => {
      return (
        <div>
          {ingredient}
        </div>
        );
    });

    return (
      <div className="panel" onClick={(e) => this.handleToggle(e)}>
        <h4>{this.props.item.name}</h4>
        <div
          className="panel-collapse"
          style={{height: currentHeight + "px"}}>
          <div ref="inner">
            {ingredients}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      popup: true,
      items: [
        {
          name: "Tofu tacos",
          ingredients: [
            "Tofu",
            "Chili powder",
            "Onion",
            "Cumin",
            "Oregano",
            "Paprika",
            "Salt",
            "Pepper",
            "Taco shells",
            "Lettuce",
            "Mozarella cheese"
          ] // end of ingredients array
        }, // end of first item
        {
          name: "Spaghetti",
          ingredients: [
            "pasta",
            "sauce"
          ]
        } // end of second item
      ] // end of items array
    } // end of this.state
    this.togglePopup = this.togglePopup.bind(this);
    this.addRecipe = this.addRecipe.bind(this);
  } // end of constructor

  togglePopup() {
    console.log("close fired");
    this.setState({
      popup: !this.state.popup
    });
  }

  addRecipe(food) {
    console.log(food);
    let foods = this.state.items;
    this.setState = ({
      items: foods.push(food)
    });
    console.log(this.state.items);
  }

  render() {
    const allitems = this.state.items.map(oneitem => (
      <Recipes item={oneitem} />
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        {allitems}
        {this.state.popup ? <Addpopup addRecipe={this.addRecipe} closeMe={this.togglePopup} /> : null}
        <Mainbutton toggleClose={this.togglePopup}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Addpopup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      food: ""
    };
    this.changeFood = this.changeFood.bind(this);
    this.addRec = this.addRec.bind(this);
  }

  changeFood(e) {
    this.setState({
      food: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state.food);
  }

  addRec() {
    let food = this.state.food;
    this.props.addRecipe(food);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="popup">
        <div className="popup-inner">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Food" onChange={this.changeFood}></input><br/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Ingredients (seperated by commas)"></input><br/>
          <button onClick={this.addRec}>Add recipe</button>
          <button onClick={this.props.closeMe}>close me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Headline extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Recipes</h1>
        <br/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Headline />
        <Box />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById("app");

ReactDOM.render(<App />, app);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click `Add Recipe` button then you are reassigning the `this.setState` which i think is a typo. In your `addRecipe` function you have following line

```
this.setState = ({
  items: foods.push(food)
});
```

Change this line to

```
this.setState({
   // Array.push return length of array. So use spread operator like this
   items: [...foods, food]
});
```

Comment: better to mention this issue also: it should be `items: [...foods, food]` otherwise items will become a number, it will be no longer an array :)

Comment: It's always the dumbest thing with me. ... Thank you for your help

Comment: @MayankShukla Right, Didn't notice that one :D